# Toolbar with Image overlay center and Scroll behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, layout

I'm creating a detailed activity and I have a curved Toolbar and in the center of the Toolbar I have a rounded ImageView, the problem is that on differents screens the image is not centered.

What I want to achieve is :

1.- Create a Toolbar with the back arrow button and one icon on the right

I have it defined as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curve_toolbar_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.09" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pew"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_conokstraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_example"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti_ex1"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_ex1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Ex1" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti_ex2"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_ex2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Ex2" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti_ex3"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_ex3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="SSID" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ti_ex4"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_ex4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Ex4"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_activation_background"
                        android:text="Example1"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/button_selected_text_color" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_activation_background"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Example2"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/button_selected_text_color" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_activation_background"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Example3"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/button_selected_text_color" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Whatever" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </ScrollView>
```

But I'm sure I'm doing it wrong because I have to play with the margins to be exactly as the left arrow, that I've added it as below :

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
binding.toolbarCreateQr.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
binding.toolbarCreateQr.setNavigationOnClickListener { finish() }
```

2.- Add this `View` that is centered manually overlaying the toolbar the same on all screen devices, now I have this: Left(Normal device) Right (Small device)

[image]

3.- I have a container below and on my small screen is not showing correctly, even if I add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />`. Now there are two ways of doing it, just adding a ScrollView for the container and forgetting about the Toolbar, and add a ScrollBehaviour to convert this Toolbar to a rectangle, and move this floating button to the toolbar itself (or leaving it floating).

The container I have is as below, is not scrolling and I'm using a CardView to make it rounded and looks like a form module, if you think there's another way to do that just answer!

By the way, the drawable resource that I'm using for the curved Toolbar is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-80dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

or I've been using this also but didn't work as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200.0"
    android:viewportHeight="100.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:pathData="M200,0H0v4.5h0v75.8h0c17.8,10.2 56,17.2 100.5,17.2c44.5,0 81.6,-7 99.5,-17.2h0V4.5h0V0z" />
</vector>
```

### Edit

First iteration, I want to be like the image I've sent but responsive for all the devices, and if it's not responsive now is that somehting I'm doing wrong with the Constraints.
Second iteration, I want to have this curve toolbar completely flat in case I arrive to the collapsion with the block of content (where I have all the textViews, EditText) with the image overlayed.
Note I have to show also the textView below the icon centered on the Toolbar.

Regarding the curve Toolbar, what I thought is to have a View on the top of the view and when scrolling it fakes this curve to flat, but I'm open to different ways.

Comment: First of all, is it a typo here that you close your toolbar ` />`  before adding the views? The toolbar is a view group and you can add the View into the toolbar.  Second, how is your container constraint? Could you add a little sketch to show how the alignment from toolbar to container is supposed to be? Thirdly, could you try to explain more precisely what issue you have with the scroll view?

Comment: I have them outside the toolbar, I've tried to put inside the toolbar but then I'm not sure how to process with the steps I add on the question

Comment: Please add your layout which contains the toolbar and the container

Comment: @Tobi could you check my edit please? I guess now I have a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, okay, so there are multiple questions at once, which makes it harder to give a complete answer. (Think about asking single question for each issue in the future. I hope I am guessing correctly which view represents which part of the question. Also consider more concise id names :)

**1. The right toolbar icon**

This one is fully encapsulated within the toolbar and could therefore actually be part of the toolbar.

Option 1 (inside Toolbar):
If it's inside the toolbar you can nicely constraint in to the `parent`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    .... >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pew"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Option 2 (separate view):
You can constraint it to the toolbar instead of the parent. With this setup it will always be vertically centered inside the Toolbar and by `marginEnd="16dp"` you can move it inside as much as you want.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_pew"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

**2. The centered img:**
To have it nicely aligned with the toolbar, align it bottom to bottom and add a negative margin equals to half the height of your img:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-38dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

It's more tricky to always have it same "size". On you pictures it actually **has the same size!** In an absolute perspective. So what you want is a relative same size compared to the screen and not a real same size. So setting `width="76dp"` will look different on different sized screens. Try making it relative.

An option to make it relative could be like this (the image would always be 1/5 of the screen width; changing the weights adjusts it):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="2"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    <View
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**3. ScrollView:**
I'm still not 100% sure whether I understood your problems. But from what I see is that you might have set your attributes for the scrollview not properly. Setting `layout_height="wrap_content"` makes the scrollView as large as the content. Then you obviously cannot scroll as the content has the same size as the scrollview. Change it to a fixed size or `match_parent`. This way the scrollview is bound to your screen. And the large content inside can be scrolled through.

**4. Curved to flat animation:**
For such animations I usually use a MotionLayout. For yours I could think of following setup:

1. A rectangular view that is fixed and represents the collapsed bar.
2. A semicircle view underneath that represents the curved part.
3. The motion layout changes `scaleY` of the second view to 0 (onSwipe or you setProgress() depending on your scroll state) which makes it disappear smoothly.

**Example:** https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-1/

Comment: This is android:layout_marginBottom="-38dp" better than adding constraints?....

Comment: Why "better than"? You need both. Having a constraint bottom to bottom aligns it to the bottom and then you can move it down by a negative  margin

Comment: Something I cannot test now but you could try is constraining both sides to the bottom of the toolbar to get it centered: `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"` and `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"`. Then you might not need a margin at all.

Comment: And what about the collapsing? How to move from oval to flat?

Comment: can you show a screenshot on how it should look collapsed? And also precisely WHEN it should be collapsed?

Comment: @Skizo please see my updated suggestion regarding the collapsing

Comment: could you add an example for that 4.

Comment: About the animation, perhaps only with the scroll on the container is enough...

Comment: Sure, take this as an example: https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-1/ here it changes the height of the entire toolbar. If you split the toolbar in two views, only adjust one of them.

Comment: Is it the same using views inside a Toolbar?

Comment: "the same"? no. Still possible? Sure. The MotionLayout can only animate top level views. So the Toolbar. But if the content of the toolbar is constraint to it's bounds they will adjust together with the toolbar. You could also think about having a MotionLayout **inside** of your Toolbar. Then you can directly animate the views.

Comment: May you add an example of how to scroll just the container? without the toolbar + centered button+ Text?

Comment: After looking through the provided example link. What details are unclear?

Comment: I still need to know how can I do this responsive for all the devices it still looking wrong on small devices

Comment: Which part? Please be more precise and show your updates in the question if you want further input

Comment: I'm talking about the toolbar... check how it looks on my device it's updated...

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Did you try my suggestion in point **2.** ? I added an example to it. Please have a look